# Are there any known cases of HTTP clients not supporting relative redirects?

Tags: http, redirect, cross-browser, http-headers

Relative redirects (i.e. relative URLs in the HTTP Location: header) were originally not supported according to [RFC 2616, section 14.30](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30). However this was described as a "bug in the spec", and was later changed in [RFC 7231, section 7.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2). Thus relative redirects are now "officially supported".

My question is: Are there any known cases of HTTP clients (browsers, tools, libraries..) *not* supporting relative redirects?

**Update:**
Alternatively, a valid answer could provide a exhaustive list of HTTP clients which are known to accept relative redirects, along with version number ranges.

Comment: I am now tempted to write an http client that doesn't support relative redirects. :-)

Comment: I don't think that anyone can provide an exhaustive list...

Comment: @MrTux I don't see why not. The web is full of info about "browser support" for feature X or Y, including version numbers. See for example caniuse.com. Also I am sure I'm not the first one to face this problem, and every developer that already faced this either got the info from somewhere else, or did some testing themselves (and thus compiled such a "list")

Answer (score 4):

I was doing some research and it seems that in fact most browsers (and also Googles search bot) support the feature. I was not able to get a definitive list though. Some 10000 http clients may eventually exist, each of them has their own way to handle the header fields (some may even ignore it completely).

As RFC 7231 is quite new (2014) my recommendation would be to not count on it. Following [Postel's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) ("Be conservative in what you send, be liberal in what you accept") I think sticking with the definite standard is always a good idea and just adding the domain to the redirect isn't much trouble.

Comment: It's not that easy. If used e.g. with apache httpd, the Location header might get rewritten automatically.

Comment: I definitely don't need a list with 10000 clients but perhaps a list of most used ones would help. Regarding Postel: RFC 7321 actually amended what was considered by the editors to be "a bug in the [RFC 2616] spec", and it was also argued that this had always been supported by all major browsers. Re. "Adding the domain to the redirect isn't much trouble": That depends. In my use case (a complex proxying scenario) the server doesn't even know the original domain **nor** (more important) the protocol (the proxy acts as a https tunnel as well).

Answer (score 0):

> "According to the HTTP protocol, the Location header must contain an
>   absolute URI.[5] When redirecting from one page to another within the
>   same site, it is a common mistake to use a relative URI. As a result
>   most browsers tolerate relative URIs in the Location header, but some
>   browsers display a warning to the end user."

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#Using_server-side_scripting_for_redirection:

---

Personally speaking, I've been using relative redirects for many years and they work with every single desktop/mobile browser and search bots I've tested with. 
You can test, for example, google bot by using the `fetch as google` tool on the webmasters dashboard.

This is probably a bit outside of the scope but google also follows `JavaScript` redirects (`window.location`).

Comment: Wikipedia is not an authoritative reference; the RFCs are. Please see RFC 7231, as pointed out in the question.

Comment: The wikipedia article cited the RFC  HTTP protocol.

Comment: If it cited RFC 2616, then it was citing an obsolete RFC, as you would know if you had followed the links in my question. By the way I don't know which version of wikipedia were you looking at, but the section you linked to actually says: "HTTP/1.1 allows for either a relative URI reference or an absolute URI reference." and cites RFC 7231 (and this text has not been edited since July 2014).